# Problem with CakePHP using autoModel when it shouldn't

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I am getting an error in my view:

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Model.id' in 'where clause' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 525]
>   $sql    =   "SELECT `Model`.`model_id`, `Model`.`pic_location`, `Model`.`model_name` FROM `models` AS `Model`   WHERE `Model`.`id` = '20'    LIMIT 1"
>   $error  =   "1054: Unknown column 'Model.id' in 'where clause'"
>   $out    =   null

My model is unfortunately named "Model", due to the legacy database I am working with.  I have used debug and determined that it is using primaryKey of 'id' (as also displayed in the SQL above), despite my model code (see below) explicitly setting the primaryKey to 'model_id'.

The database table is models with a primary key of model_id, so I can only assume the system is using an autoModel.

My model code is 'model.php':

```
    <?php class Model extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Model';
var $primaryKey = 'model_id';

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
var $hasMany = array(
    'Pic' => array(
        'className' => 'Pic',
        'foreignKey' => 'model_name',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);}?>
```

I originally created the by hand, and when I hit this error, I baked it... with identical results (except I didn't include the empty fields in the hasMany relationship).

I have turned application level caching off temporarily, and cleared the cache, but nothing helps.  How can I make it use my model code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to rename your `Model` model to something else. Your `Model` class extends `AppModel`, which in turn extends the base model class, which is also called `Model`. You're bound to get into trouble this way.

If you have a legacy database, just set the [`$useTable` attribute](http://book.cakephp.org/view/436/useTable) to use a table with a name different from your model.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but wasn't sure.  Have done that and it has fixed it.  Thanks.